# Is there a not within range (~=) operator in swift?

Tags: swift

Swift has a cool operator that returns true if an element is within range of two prior elements.  Is there a not operator for it, which would return true if the last element is not within range of the first two?

Example of `~=`

```
/// If close is within ema and twentyBelowEma
if ema...twentyBelowEma ~= close {
   self = .aboveSupportAndEma
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want something like `!~=`?

Comment: @Sweeper, yes that is what I want... Ah yes...I should just implement that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always just define your own operator!

[`~=` is defined by default for all `RangeExpression`s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangeexpression/2892547), so your `!~=` could also be defined for all `RangeExpression`s:

```
infix operator !~=: ComparisonPrecedence

extension RangeExpression {
    static func !~=(lhs: Self, rhs: Bound) -> Bool {
        return !(lhs ~= rhs)
    }
}
```